# Change setTitle to setImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to developing so excuse me if i say or ask something that doesn't make sense at all.
I am working on this project in which i want to play audio files mp3. I allready made a play pause button. I got it to work that music plays and when i press on the button "pause" the text changes into "play". But i want to make the playpause button an image instead of plain text.
This is my "old" line of code:

```
- (IBAction)playOrPause:(id)sender {
  if(self.myAudioPlayer.playing == YES) {
    [self.myAudioPlayer pause];
      [self.playPauseButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I tried changing the last line to setImage:

```
[self.playPauseButton setImage:@"Playicon.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but that doesn't seem to work immediately.

Thanks

Comment: Place the 'else' part of code as well for setImage option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UIImage` instance. Try:

```
[self.playPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Where `@"play"` is name of your image. (Do not forget to add images in your project.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to two images to your project. 1. Play.png 2.Pause.png

```
[self.button setImage:@"Play.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setImage:@"Pause.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

- (IBAction)playOrPause:(UIButton *)sender 
{
   if(sender.selected)
   {
       sender.selected = NO;
       [self.musicPlayer play];
   }
   else
   {
       sender.selected = YES;
       [self.musicPlayer pause];
   }       
}
```